# iOS ViewController SIGABRT

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ipad, sigabrt

I have came across a small problem I cannot solve since an hour... I'm new to iOS so probably it is something which you will notice after a second ;) I was looking for simular posts on SO, but didnt find the satisfying answer...

There is a `SplitViewController` as above (I've added a tableView on the left and textView on the right using XIB). When Im trying to compile and run my project I've got the following error:

> Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT".

I would like to have one split view with correlating tableView and textView. What I'm doing wrong?

SplitViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SplitViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end
```

SplitViewController.m:

```
#import "SplitViewController.h"

@implementation SplitViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize textView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [self setTextView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

TestAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SplitViewContoller;
@interface TestAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@end
```

TestAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"
#import "SplitViewController.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplitViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
} 
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}   
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

@end
```

and the main just for accuracy:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TestAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need in your Delegate like this `@synthesize viewController = _viewController`; you could do just like this `@synthesize viewController;` and make sure your Outlets are connected properly and if you are using iOS6 then no need to use `viewDidUnload`

Comment: Why is your SplitViewController not subclassing UISplitViewController?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause a crash, and there's really no reason to post all the boilerplate code, only the stuff you changed would be sufficient.

Comment: you would be much better off using a Master/Detail template project. Then just add a `UITextView` to the `detailViewController`

Comment: possibly your tableView declaration in SplitViewController should be strong and not weak?